# Remove Widget from QSplitter

Tags: c++, qt, qsplitter

A long time ago, someone asked the same question. [How to remove...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371599/how-to-remove-qwidgets-from-qsplitter)

This was the answer:

> When you hide() a child its space will be distributed among the other children. It will be reinstated when you show() it again.

I've tried the `QSplitter::hide()`,`show()`,`update()` functions and also `delete`.
Nothing worked.

```
//class.cpp

void PlainView::addComponent(QWidget *widget)
{
  qDebug() << _splitOne->widget(1);

  //delete current widget on index 1
  delete _splitOne->widget(1);
  //add new widget on index 1
  _splitOne->addWidget(widget);

  qDebug() << _splitOne->widget(1);
}

//output
QObject(0x0)  
QTextEdit(0xa0f580
```

The first widget was deleted and the new widget was added. But I can't see the new widget.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use delete but instead use `deleteLater()` and you'll need to remove the old widget first:

```
void PlainView::addComponent(QWidget *widget)
{
  qDebug() << _splitOne->widget(1);
  QWidget *old = _splitOne->widget(1);

  // deparenting removes the widget from the gui
  old->setParent(0);
  //delete current widget on index 1
  old->deleteLater()

  //add new widget on index 1
  _splitOne->insertWidget(1,widget);
  widget->show();

  qDebug() << _splitOne->widget(1);
}
```

Comment: i've tested your code but i got the following exception: `QObject(0x0)  
The program has unexpectedly finished.` My compiler doesnt support `auto` Message: `warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]`

Comment: This line makes troubles `setParent(NULL);`

Comment: old->setParent(0) throw the same exception `The program has unexpectedly finished`, sorry ;(