# Remove a specific QWidget from a QSplitter

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget, qsplitter

I want to remove a specific `Qwidget` from a `QSplitter` (or the`QSplitter`with it is the best choice i thing) after i create 2-3 of them.

To do this, i thing that i need to get the index of every widget that i create.

This is my code:

```
class Windows(self):
  list1 = [widget1, widget2, widget3]
  counter = 0
  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

    self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)

    self.spliiter_2 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
    self.splitter_2.addwidget(self.splitter)

  def addWidget(self):
    if counter == 1:
      self.splitter.addWidget(Windows.list1[0])
      counter += 1

    if counter == 2:
      counter += 1
      self.splitter.addWidget(Windows.list1[1])

    if counter == 3:
      self.splitter.addWidget(Windows.list1[2])
      counter += 1


  def deleteWidget(self):
    ??????????????
```

As you can see above, i create a QSplitter in the class Windows, and then i create another one (`self.splitter_2`) where i put the first one.

Every time that i press a combination of keys, i call the `addWidget` method, and it adds a widget (that depends of the variable counter) from the list1.

If i want to delete the 2nd widget(for example), how can i do it, without deleting the first widget?. I thing that i need the index, but i do not know how to get it.

I have created a button that calls the `deleteWidget`method, by the way.

I read about the `hide()` form, but i do not know how to specified it. But, i would rather delete it completely.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove QWidgets from QSplitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371599/how-to-remove-qwidgets-from-qsplitter)

Comment: Thank for your advice, but it is not a duplicate because i am asking for delete a "specific" widget. The one that you are showing (i saw this one) deletes all the widget.

Comment: First you need to get the widget, by index or search in childs, then hide it.

Comment: Are you talking of `QSplitter.indexOf()` . I tried that, but i do not know what to do with that. I am sorry, i´m new in Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `deleteWidget()` function could look like this:

```
def deleteWidget(self, index):
    delete_me = self.splitter.widget(index)
    delete_me.hide()
    delete_me.deleteLater()
```

We need `hide()` because according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#details)

> When you hide() a child, its space will be distributed among the other
>   children.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for late reply. This worked for me. Thank you again.